# How to count 1 in cell A for every number in cell B

Tags: excel

I'm trying to come up with a way that I can count 1 for every x in another cell.  Specificaly I need for Cell A1 to increase by 1 for every 2.5 in cell B1, and only in whole numbers, not in decimals.  So if cell B1 is 2.4, cell A1 would show 0.  If it's 2.5, A1 would show 1.  If it's 4.9, A1 would still show 1, etc.

I've been using the ROUNDDOWN function for a while, and just dividing cell A1 by 2.5, then rounding that down.  However, I came across a situation where I need to count 2 for every 5 specifically in multiples of 2.  So 4.9 would be 0, 5.0 would be 2.  9.9 would still be 2, 10.0 would be 4.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Edit: So simple but so genius!  Don't know why I didn't think of that, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you describe I would say you just have to multiply by 2 like this 2*ROUNDDOWN(A1/5,0)

Answer (score 1):

A more flexible method where A1 is your divisor and A2 is what you're evaluating:

```
=IF(MOD(A2,$A$1)=0,(A2/$A$1)*1,0)
```